# form_tag cannot align button and input box - rails 4 bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to align my button and form input tag however nothing appears to be working, if i use the normal HTML form for bootstrap.

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Go!</button>
   </span>
</div>
```

I get an aligned input box and button, however when i use the form_tag helper with the following in my erb;

```
<%= form_tag search_nut_databases_path, :class => "form-inline", method: :get do %>
<div class="input-group">
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control",  :placeholder => "search database" %>
   <span class="input-group-btn">
     <%= submit_tag 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
 </span>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

I get a misaligned box, i've checked the css and nothing should be affecting it

thanks

Answer (score 0):

enclosed your code into form group class.. like following

```
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Go!</button>
    </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you were able to resolve this, but I too had a similar problem and was able to get the alignments properly.

Here is the snippet that I tried amending

```
<%= form_tag(search_nut_databases_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form", :class => "form-inline") do %>
        <div class="input-group">
         <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => "form-control", placeholder: "search database" %>
        </div>
        <!--This actually works for the button-->
        <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-default") do %>
                <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Search
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The only problem I still face is the fact of customizing the size of the text_field_tag, since the :class => 'input-large' doesn't get triggered when "form-control" is present.

However, I hope this bit of code was helpful to you.

Aks

Comment: Instead of using :class => "form-inline" in the form_tag. I have used :class => "navbar-form navbar-left" as I want a specific way of displaying my form. Cheers